# PHP unlink() encoding

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I have a form where users can upload files.

When a user tries to upload a file with danish characters like this: `æ ø test Ø Å.pdf`,

I get a file path like this in the backend: `content/uploads/u00f8-test-u00d8-u00c51.pdf`, even though the file is saved with the original filename.

The problem occurs when I try to `unlink()` the file by providing the above path.

How should I proccess the file path so that `unlink()` would delete it?

Comment: You should normalize the filename before saving it to backend. Remove special characters from filename.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "special character". What should be "special" about it? There are only characters. Lot's of 'em buggers.

Comment: @arkascha,  my bad. renamed 'special' to 'danish'.

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Server runs Linux

Comment: *"I get this [...] path, even though the file is saved with the original name"* – what exactly does that mean? Either it's saved with name a or b, can't be both somehow.

Comment: Also, in general, you typically don't want to save files with a user-supplied name at all. Not only because of security concerns (filename `"../../../../passwd"`) which you would have to sanitize the heck out of, but also specifically because dealing with non-ASCII filenames is a nightmare. Generate your own completely random file name (file content hash or a UUID are good ideas), and save the original filename as metadata in a database somewhere.

Comment: I use a Gravity Forms (WordPress plugin), which stores the file with original filename (I cannot manipulate this), but returns the path provided above.

Comment: I just need to store the file, attach it to email and unlink() it straight away, so that is not a big concern, as long as I can delete the file.

Comment: Either your example is not real or the plug-in simply strips file name information in a way that makes it impossible to recover the original. Whatever, I can see `u####` entities that have nothing to do with HTML, URLs, file systems or PHP (they *resemble* JavaScript entities though). You clearly have code that makes those replacements intentionally but we have no code to inspect.